# Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift

I am working on a social media type app and i want to implement the block feature for users but I'm encountering an error " Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type 'String'"

below is a sample of my code 
    i first declared the current user ID and Pageuser ID

```
var currentUserId: Int!
var userPageId: Int!
```

then the main code that gives the error

```
  self.userHelper.checkBanUser(with:  userPageId, toUser: defaults.string(forKey: "userId")!) { (data) in

        if data {
            self.blockLabel.isHidden = false
        }
        else {
            //
        }
    }
```

the error comes from the "userPageID "

update. this is the function to check banned users

```
 func checkBanUser(with fromUser: String,toUser: String,completionHandler : @escaping ((_ isResponse : Bool) -> Void)) {

    let urlRequest = String(format: "%@%@",BASE_BACKEND_URL,ENDPOINT_CHECK_BANN)

    Alamofire.request( urlRequest,method: .post, parameters: ["X-API-KEY": API_GENERAL_KEY,"fromUser":fromUser,"toUser":toUser])
        .responseJSON { response in

             let itemz = response.result.value as! NSDictionary!

             let resp = itemz?.value(forKey: "respon") as! String

            if (resp == "banned"){

                completionHandler (true)

            } else {

                completionHandler (false)

            }



    }
}
```

Comment: May you please show us the method `checkBanUser`? or at least its interface

Comment: i just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an Int where it needs a string. Try this instead:

`self.userHelper.checkBanUser(with: "\(userPageId)", toUser: defaults.string(forKey: "userId")!)`